# How do I fix the error 'No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How do I debug and fix this error

> No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc

Analyser doesn't show any cause.

Comment: Use Instruments, not the static analyzer. The static analyzer is not a runtime profiler.

Comment: It sounds to me like that message may be saying that the STATE the program's in prevents calling malloc.  Eg, in a "machine thread" that is not allowed to use malloc, or in some sort of error handling situation where the malloc pool is unstable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instruments to check for leaks and memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Heapshot in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310821/how-can-i-determine-which-objects-hold-references-to-other-objects-that-are-caus)

Basically there method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an intuition of your code and another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the picker to run, stop recording, search for there ivar (datePickerView), drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]